# How to get all products id with price based on cart rule in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have to show configurable product's price associated with my cart price rules in the product listing page.

Suppose I have a product who's price is $20 if anyone purchase that product more than 10 than the price would be $17/piece and if someone purchase more than 20, then the price would be $15.

So I have to show those price which is associated with cart price rule, on the product listing page. like - 20 items at just $15 , 10 items at just $17 and so on.

Comment: Cart price rules are associated with attributes of the **cart**. This makes a general solution hard to design in a way that makes sense for the user. How should the product listing anticipate what is going to be in the cart? For your scenario, where only the qty of the current product is taken into account, **tier prices** are a better fit. With them it will be easier to display the right price dependent on the entered qty.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get tier price associated with products?

Comment: In "advanced pricing", as described here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-advanced-pricing.html